# Do blue and red shift oppose relativity?

Tags: speed-of-light, relativity, relative-motion

The speed of light is constant does not depend upon the relative velocity of observer. But why there is blue and red shift ? Is it only for the reason that for this case the source of light is moving ? Or there is some other cause ?

Answer (score 0):

The blue/redshift is due to a change in frequency (or equivalently wavelength), not speed. An energy-$E$ photon has momentum $E/c$, frequency $\omega:=E/\hbar$ and wavenumber $\omega/c$. Its four-frequency $k^\mu$ then satisfies $k_0=\omega,\,|\mathbf{k}|=\frac{\omega}{c}$ so $k_\mu k^\mu=0$. Although a Lorentz transformation preserves this last condition (and hence the fact that the photon has speed $c$), the calculation $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\gamma & \gamma\beta\\
\gamma\beta & \gamma
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1
\end{array}\right)=\gamma\left(1+\beta\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1
\end{array}\right)=\sqrt{\dfrac{1+\beta}{1-\beta}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1
\end{array}\right)$ tells us that a Lorentz transformation scales the four-frequency.

Comment: I haven't studied relativity mathematically, so can you please explain it other way or theoritically ?

Comment: @SoubhadraMaiti Red/blueshift is due to a change in the wave's frequency, not its speed. The speed relevant to this effect is that of the source, not the light itself.